# Filter out rows of multiple dataframes in a for loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of 3 dataframes which contain various names and numbers :

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

df1 example:
| Names | Number |
|-------|--------|
| Cat   | 45     |
| Bat   | 1      |
| Dog   | 78     |
| Goat  | 45     |

df2 example:

| Names | Number |
|-------|--------|
| Pizza | 2      |
| Bagel | 17     |
| Pasta | 3      |
| Bread | 88     |

df3 example:
| Names     | Number |
|-----------|--------|
| Rose      | 6      |
| Sunflower | 3      |
| Tulip     | 6      |
```

I also have a list of names for each dataframe and underlying names stored as variables:

```
object_types = ['animals', 'food', 'plants']
selected_names = {'animals': ['Cat', 'Bat'], 'food': ['Pizza', 'Apple'], 'plants': ['Rose']}
```

What I would like to end up with is a dictionary with the types as the keys, and dataframes as values. e.g.

```
filtered_dfs= {'animals': df1, ....}
```

where the individual dataframes only contain rows with matching entries to their type in the `names` variable (so only rows for 'Cat' and 'Bat' are kept in df1)

I was thinking of doing something as below:

```
filtered_dfs={}
for objecttype, df, selectedname in zip(object_types, dfs, selected_names):
   filtered_dfs[objecttype] = df
   for i in selectedname[objecttype]:
       df[df['Names'].isin(i)]
```

where i want to assign the type and dataframes as k,v pairs in the dictionary, then access each df based upon the type,and filter using the dictionary of names. HoweverI can't seem to fit in the filtering of the dataframs in my loop. can someone help me solution please?

Comment: Are you using type to mean something other than datatype (float, string, integer, etc.)? "type" is a keyword in Python and you shouldn't use it as a variable name.

Comment: @Linden thanks for your comment - i updated my variables name to avoid it

Comment: You still have "filtered_dfs[type] = dfs". and "for i in name[type]:" in your question. Is this intentional?

Comment: sorry no, it was my mistake, I have fixed it

Comment: Also you're accessing a variable called "dfs" in your for loop. Shouldn't this be "df"? "dfs" will set the dictionary variable to the entire list of dataframes (as that's what you've set it to in the first line of your code).

Comment: And in the last line of your for loop, you're just returning a filtered dataframe. You're not assigning it to anything.

Comment: And you might want to consider renaming the dict of names or the column in the dataframes as "Names" and "names" are very similar so easy to mix up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?:

```
object_types = ['animals', 'food', 'plants']
selected_names = {'animals': ['Cat', 'Bat'], 'food': ['Pizza', 'Apple'], 'plants': ['Rose']}
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
filtered_dfs = {}

for df, obj_type in zip(dfs, object_types):
    i = selected_names[obj_type]
    new_df = df[df['Names'].isin(i)]
    filtered_dfs[obj_type] = new_df
```

Comment: yes exactly what i need, thanks for help and sorry for my poor mistakes sir

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code as follows:

```
filtered_dfs={}
for name in names.keys():
    for df in dfs:
        if any(df['Names'].isin(names[name])):
            filtered_dfs[name] = df
```

This logics does not assume the dict key sequence is in sync with the dataframe type (whether holding 'animals', 'food' or 'plants' type ) sequence. That is, does not mandate `df1` must be of `animals` type (can be `df2` of `animals` type and still can extract correctly).  This logics should be more generic.

Resut:

```
print(filtered_dfs)


{'animals':   Names  Number
 0   Cat      45
 1   Bat       1
 2   Dog      78
 3  Goat      45,
 'food':    Names  Number
 0  Pizza       2
 1  Bagel      17
 2  Pasta       3
 3  Bread      88,
 'plants':        Names  Number
 0       Rose       6
 1  Sunflower       3
 2      Tulip       6}
```